# Subdivision Surface Modifier is bridging/filling in the area under a curve

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am modeling the anvil from Blender Guru's intermediate tutorial and have encountered an issue. When I add the Subdivision Surface modifier, Blender partially fills the area inside of one of the curves. I have tried creasing the bottom edge, but that does not seem to have helped.

The included pictures are using the modifier with the default settings. When I messed with the settings, nothing appreciable changed with the anvil.

If anyone has insight into this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image: Without the Modifier]

[image: With the Modifier]

Comment: Looks like subdivision of a concave ngon.  Is your bottom made out of quads?

Comment: No my bottom is not made out of quads. I can try making it into quads. 

Here is an image of the bottom: https://imgur.com/VVJajUE

Comment: Thank you! Changing the bottom to quads fixed everything.

Comment: Solved! https://imgur.com/5B9W5dE